# How to change the flow direction of the background Image?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a panorama app, and is localized. it is applied the flow direction for the app:

```
FlowDirection flow = (FlowDirection)Enum.Parse(typeof(FlowDirection), AppResources.ResourceFlowDirection);
RootFrame.FlowDirection = flow;
```

this way it applies the direction for the app, but the problem is that I don't want the direction of the background Image also change:

```
<phone:Panorama.Background>
<ImageBrush ImageSource="/MyApp;component/Assets/CustomBackground.png"/>
</phone:Panorama.Background>
```

So I thought I can change the `FlowDirection` of this background image, or use its name to change it programmatically or add something like `StackPanel` and change its direction, but at the end neither one worked.

How to not allow the direction of the background image to change, or how to assign prefered direction to it? *(this is a windows phone 8 app)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the FlowDirection of the Panorama itself to be LeftToRight, but change the FlowDirection of the PanoramaItem controls to match the parent control of your Panorama

Example:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">

     <!--Panorama control-->
    <phone:Panorama Title="my application" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
        <phone:Panorama.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/PanoramaApp1;component/Assets/PanoramaBackground.png"/>
        </phone:Panorama.Background>

        <!--Panorama item one-->
        <phone:PanoramaItem Header="first item" FlowDirection="{Binding FlowDirection, ElementName=LayoutRoot}">

        </phone:PanoramaItem>

        <!--Panorama item two-->
        <phone:PanoramaItem FlowDirection="{Binding FlowDirection, ElementName=LayoutRoot}">
        </phone:PanoramaItem>
    </phone:Panorama>
</Grid>
```

Also the app will flow to whatever the Culture of the phone is. There is not a need to store the FlowDirection. Taking this knowledge, you would remove the FlowDirection property from the Grid (LayoutRoot) but leave it on the Panorama/PanoramaItems so they are set correctly